# Extremely Varying r squared score on small dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am currently in the middle of an regression-assignent. We were handed a very small dataset consisting of 47 datapoints with 2 features and 1 target value. It looks like this:

```
N level,species,Plant Weight(g)
L,brownii,0.3008
L,brownii,0.3288
M,brownii,0.3304
M,brownii,0.388
M,brownii,0.406
H,brownii,0.3955
H,brownii,0.3797
H,brownii,0.2962
```

For each plant there are 3L, 3M and 3H (so 9 for each plant). The assignment is getting the best r squared score, but 6 data points are held back (6 data points removed from the dataset I got, meaning for each flower (there are 6) one data point of either L, M or H are removed. As you can see in the sample abvoe, one L from "brownii" is removed. I have tried several regression algorithms, tried KFolds, LeaveOneOut and splitting the dataset manually, but it seems that the dataset is so small that the depending on the test data, the result varies A LOT. On some test data I can get a score of 0.95, but on some I might only get 0.2.

Is there any way of achieving any consistency here?

Comment: I have a suggestion that might help pinpoint the problem. R-squared (R2) can be calculated as "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)" and tells you what fraction of the dependent data variance is explained by the model, that is, an R-squared value of 0.95 means that the model explains 95% of the dependent data variance. Using numpy arrays this is trivially calculated as "R2 = 1.0 - (abs_err.var() / dep_data.var()" so that if you manually inspect the abs_err.var() and dep_data.var() values it can highlight the problem area.